# How do I get localised version of current URL in a template?

Tags: django, templates, url, localization

I'm moving my language-in-url engine from transurlvania to [i18nurls](https://github.com/brocaar/django-i18nurls) (a patch accepted to [future version of django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns)) but I'm missing something similar to transurlvania's awsome `{% this_page_in_lang 'cs' %}` to implement generic language switching link.

I can't figure out how to achieve this using only django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#std:templatetag-language, I guess an answer to this question should be:

```
{% language 'cs' %}
    <a href="{% url some_view arg1='value' %}">whatever</a>
{% endlanguage %}
```

Comment: This requires knowing the name of the current view in advance, which is not necessarily readily available.